# C++ compile multiple files with same function name

Tags: c++, c

In the printNumbers.h file

```
//Write a function getNumber() and put your favourite number inside! 
//I will then compile the program and print everyone's favourite number!
int getNumber(void);
```

If i want something like to keep printing out three people's favourite numbers

```
int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < 9999) {
         if(counter % 3 == 0) {
             //Print out the first person's number
             printf("My number is %d\n", getNumber();
         } else if (counter % 3 == 1) {
             //Print out the second person's number
             printf("My number is %d\n", getNumber();
         } else {
             //Print out the third person's number
             printf("My number is %d\n", getNumber();
         }

         //Keep printing everyone's numbers until counter reaches 9999

         counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

3 people give me  C++ files they wrote and I rename each to A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp. It could be in random order so they don't know if their file will end up being A B or C

Example of the c++ file they could have written

```
int getNumber() {
    //Each person can write their own function to return whatever number they want
    int myNumber = 1;
    return myNumber;
}
```

**Is there anyway, for me to compile the programs and use getNumber() from A.cpp for the first call, from B.cpp for the second call and from C.cpp from the third call, then repeat.**

I could name the function names in the while loop getNumber1() getNumber2() getNumber3() and change the function names in the three C++ files but when someone writes the getNumber() function they don't know if it will end up being A B or C. Everyone's getNumber() function should be called getNumber().

.

**EDIT:** Lots of people are suggesting namespaces. I have no control over the .h file and the ADT the people are given, so the program they write wont use namespaces. Also many people might submit C++ files to me and I have to randomly group theem into groups of 3 (since my program can only print 3 people's numbers) so they don't know what namepspace to use.
.

**EDIT:** A few people are suggesting modifying the .h file or the program the people write. We all get given the .h file and we cannot change it. We submit the files(like the example) to the school and **they are able to do what my main function does** (I have no idea how they do it). My main function will allow the users to test their getNumber() function better before they submit, so it is a separate program to the school that the users can optionally use.

If anything seems confusing or unclear please ask me questions to clarify my question!

Thank you.

Comment: Is this kind of thing not what namespaces are for?

Comment: No, there isn't. You can't link against all their translation units and have multiple definitions of the same function.

Comment: Compile with `-DgetNumber=getNumberXXX` with a different XXX for each file...

Comment: Instead of repeatedly editing the question to reveal more constraints, it may be easier to just include your entire assignment verbatim.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Hey mark, there is no assignment. This is just a side project. The Main assignment is something like write a getNumber() function and then the school will compile 3 people's getNumber() function together and repeatedly print out their numbers.

What I am making is another simmilar program to how the school will print out 3 people's numbers but include more stuff to help people test their function

Comment: @Friedpanseller how the C language related to this question? It seems to be about C++.

Comment: @user2079303 everyone's function is written in C and the magic people make it all work so it's possible with C, that's why I included it. I'm using C++ and that might bring better methods to solve the problem that's why

Comment: @Friedpanseller You should mention that everyone writes C in your question. Right now your question contradicts multiple times: *"people give me C++ files"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are getting their cpp files, which you do not want to change, instead of compiling and linking them, you could include them in your cpp, like this

```
namespace A {
  #include "A.cpp"
}
namespace B {
  #include "B.cpp"
}
namespace C {
  #include "C.cpp"
}

int main ()
{
  A::getNumber();
  B::getNumber();
  C::getNumber();
}
```

Comment: A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp #includes the .h for the ADTto work.

I just rtied compiling it with your method. Lots of overload function errors:

ambiguous call to overloaded function and no everloaded function takes X amount of arguments

Comment: Do the .h files have include guards?

Comment: Ohh okay they didn't have include guards. I removed all the #include .h from each .cpp file and it worked.. Although it was best if the cpp files could remain unedited, removing the #includes doesn't seem like alot of work. So this is a really good solution. Thanks!!

Comment: A workaround I did was make the #included .h files blank so they wouldn't include them, and include a renamed one once myself in my main cpp file, so I no longer need to delete the #includes from everyone's cpp files!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to put multiple different functions with identical name and parameter lists into global namespace, even from different translation units.

However, C++ lets you use *namespaces* to distinguish among identically-named functions:

a.cpp

```
namespace a {
    int getNumber() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

b.cpp

```
namespace b {
    int getNumber() {
        return 205;
    }
}
```

The caller can distinguish between `getNumber` functions by using context resolution operator:

```
 if(counter % 3 == 0) {
     //Print out the first person's number
     printf("My number is %d\n", a::getNumber();
 } else if (counter % 3 == 1) {
     //Print out the second person's number
     printf("My number is %d\n", b::getNumber();
 } else {
     //Print out the third person's number
     printf("My number is %d\n", c::getNumber();
 }
```

Comment: I have no control over the .h file and the ADT so I would have to get everyone to put namespaces in just to make it work with my program as well. Which is fine i guess but slightly more work for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select function being called at runtime, here is what you can do.

Instead of giving function prototype in the header, create an array of function pointers:

```
typedef void (*GetNumberType)();
extern GetNumberType functions[5];
```

In main.cpp:

```
GetNumberType functions[5];
```

In each of A,B,C .cpp:

```
class Register
{
  Register()
  {
    int i =0;
    // find a place to put the function in
    while(functions[i]) i++;
    functions[i] = &getNumber;
  }
};

Register r;

void getNumber()
{
...
}
```

Now you can iterate over `functions` in main.cpp and call them.

Comment: In my EDIT: I wrote the .h file is given to everyone and I can't change it. Magically if they submit to the magic people they can make something like my main() function work.

Comment: I'm writing a slightly different program that people can use to help them test their function better. Program is different than the one the magic people have but I have no idea how they make it work

Comment: If you already given your header, there is nothing you can do. Or well, you can ask them to compile into shared objects (SO, DLLs) and then use dynamic linker functions to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile each user's c++-file into a stand-alone executable/DLL/callable-code, then from your main program you call these to get the numbers.

With header the same in all cases you have no other option.

Comment: This seems very promising! (but i'm not very good at all this so I have no idea how to do it) Could you expand on this a bit to guide me on how to compile them to stand-alone executable/DLL/callable-code and how to call the compiled program?

Comment: @Friedpanseller: what platform are you on? - windows, linux, mac? what ide? - MSVS, ...

Comment: Windows platform. I will deal with Linux later. Eventually my program will need to work with Linux but I'm trying to get windows to work for now.

Comment: loooooong time since i last used windows: look in the docs how to create & use dll's - it's easy, do something like putting export (IIRC) wrappers round the functions, could be as simple as #include the c++-file inside the export wrapper in a template-file which is then compiled (you are in school & need to learn this stuff ;)

Comment: @Friedpanseller: also if you are going this route you can as well place namespace wrappers around the code - would simplify things a lot

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway, for me to compile the programs and use getNumber() from A.cpp for the first call, from B.cpp for the second call and from C.cpp from the third call, then repeat.

No, there is not. There can be exactly one definition for the function `int getNumber()`.

If you want to compile them into a single program, then either

1. the people who write the source files must use a unique name each (possibly using namespaces, or simply a different function name), or if that's not an option, then
2. **you** (or whoever is responsible for compiling and linking the files) must modify the the source files that you (or they) receive so that each function has a unique name.

The option 2. can be automated using pre-processing. The c pre-processor might achieve what you're trying to do, but on the other hand, it might be simpler to write a program of your own to process the files.

Another approach could be to instead augment each separate source file with a wrapper (this modification is right up the c pre-processor's alley), that defines the `main` function which simply calls the function once. Then compile each to a separate program. Then write the Master program that spawns the other programs as child processes.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can compile each file to a dll and then load the function dynamically.